# Usefulness of blog to apply for a job different from current role

Tags: career-development, recruitment, human-resources, career-switch

I am interested in some topics that are not strictly part of day job. I'd like to start a blog talking about these to showcase a wider understanding of my field (and the related field).

Would a good blog be an efficient way to show these skills when applying to a different position or field?

**Theory**:

- **software developer** (same field): A software developer writing thoughtfully about user experience will increase the chances to become lead developer because it shows full understanding of the product (not only technical understanding).
- **school teacher** (field jump): a teacher talking about marketing in a blog may be able to transition from a teaching job to an entry level marketing job.

Comment: What you are asking is not very clear... You go from Software developper to marketing and then teacher... In theory I think that having a blog could be a good idea as far as the content is of good quality.

Comment: @dadama It'd say that depends on the actual position. Could you be more specific?

Comment: I think this question is clear.

Answer (score 4):

> Would a good blog be an efficient way to show these skills when
>   applying to a different position or field?

If you are really good in a particular domain, and can articulate it really well in a blog post, you could develop a readership.

A great blog can attract the attention of some potential employers. It's a form of networking and personal marketing, which can lead to all sorts of job possibilities. (On the other hand a poor blog can be a net negative).

While blog articles don't replace real work experience, I know from personal experience that a blog can be a great addition to your "portfolio".

Answer (score 2):

> Would a good blog be an efficient way to show these skills when applying to a different position or field?

I am not sure it would be the most *efficient* way. Generally, **while writing *about* something is fine, actually doing it is even better.** I would argue that experience of actively engaging with projects in a domain of interest, rather than merely musing about them, will carry more weight with hiring committees.

Consider what other, alternative strategies might there be for raising your profile in a field not directly related to your present occupation. Here we get into strategies for gaining experience in a given area "from scratch." One such strategy might be seeking out volunteer or freelance opportunities in this area of work. If it is teaching, try after-school tutoring support for school kids. If it is marketing, try volunteering help with graphic design, fundraising, or social media presence for some small local nonprofit. If it is coding, consider contributing to an open-source software project that you already use and believe in.

With regard to blogging, I have several concerns that prevent me from agreeing with this idea. Here are a few:

1. A personal blog (even if on professional topics) is not a standard resume item, since it is not part of formal "work experience" but more in the hobby territory. Formally, HR departments might not be able to give any weight/credit for blogging activity unless it is directly related to job function in current role (e.g. communications officer running a company intranet blog; marketing outreach staff being in charge of businesse's social media presence).
2. It may be difficult to maintian the quality of the blog due to prevance of spam or 'low quality' comments which may 'dilute' the otherwise professional appearance of the blog and potentially tarnish the author's reputation.
3. Blogging is by nature a subjective medium - it is almost impossible to avoid sharing personal opinions and perspectives on issues. That is not a problem in itself, but what you don't know is whether the person in charge of hiring you in your next prospective job will agree with what you are writing or not. There is always a multitude of opinions on any subject, and you never know how open-minded or receptive your potential future manager is to the specific perspective that you are sharing. This means that blogging can be equally likely to tarnish or augment your reputation -- to some workplace your opinions will be a good fit, to others they may be simply n/a.
4. Blogging might raise a flag for a prospective employer - if you openly share work-related information on a personal blog, how does this affect the chances that information about some proprietary product or process (intellectual property) won't slip into some of your writing? Many larger companies who have defense contracts are probably highly suspicious/weary of employees blogging on work-related topics.
5. There is nothing easier than starting a blog. However, maintaining it through regular contribution of content is much more difficult. Time pressures at work or at home may cause blogging to quickly move down on the priority list and the blog might become neglected over time. Then, you will end up in the grey area where on one hand, you don't want to completely give it up due to being too  invested in the time and effort already spent, while on the other hand it no longer represents your best effort, and therefore is less effective as a self-promotion/advertising vehicle for career growth.

I am sure there are positive aspects of work-related blogging, and that sometimes such blogs help their authors rise to even higher prominence and respect within their fields (I am sure there are plenty of examples of this in any area). Undoubtedly there are people on this forum who have been successful with work-related blogs, and hope they will share some "how to's" on how to do it right to make it work for you.

My goal is not to discourage you but to allow you to consider the various potential challenges upfront, before you plunge into it and spend too much time on something that might not be worth it in the long run. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

A blog will show that you have good theoretical knowledge of a given topic, as well as the ability to present that knowledge, in a useful way, to your readers.

It does not, however, prove so much that you have actual, practical experience regarding any given topic.

That being said, a rule of thumb would be:

**Blogging might be good, doing actual (project) work in the field would be better.**

I'd say the answer depends on the actual field and position in question:

A blog would be particularly helpful if writing (and maybe teaching, giving explanations in general) is part of the job -- obviously when it comes to journalism, technical writing etc.

In general, running your own blog would show that you're a self-motivated person, which is most mostly regarded as positive.

Commenting on your specific examples:

*"software developer (same field): A software developer writing thoughtfully about user experience will increase the chances to become lead developer because it shows full understanding of the product (not only technical understanding)."*

Certainly a blog would demonstrate knowledge about user experience / the SDLC in general if it has high-quality articles about those topics. However, another way to look at this would be: Could you instead do some kind of side project that deals with some user experience obstacles really well, for example?

*"school teacher (field jump): a teacher talking about marketing in a blog may be able to transition from a teaching job to an entry level marketing job."*

While a blog may present knowledge about marketing, it would be more vaulable to actually gain experience in marketing. What kind of marketing position are you looking for? Could your blog help you with his? For example, could you actually market products online instead of just writing about it?

It is a bit of a chicken-or-the-egg problem:

You will need some experience in a field to write meaningful blog posts about it. The more experience you have, the more useful your blog posts will probably be. But if you already have experience, is a blog necessary anymore?

Certainly a blog has some value in its own right, in addition to your work experience, however, it's not a replacement for your portfolio. Rather, it's just one part of it.